# Plural count noun (with no articles) vs (any or some)

Tags: articles

I read stuff here http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/article.htm

> *5. You use a plural count noun with no article if you mean all or any of that thing.*

This is how I interpreted it :

1. I don't like dogs. ( I don't like a *chihuahua*, a *bulldog*, a *golden retriever* , etc)
2. Do they have children? (a *Girl* or a *Boy* kid)

But what the difference when we use ***any*** for example?

like :

1. I don't like ***any*** dogs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[any](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/any) has several meanings. Two of them are:

> Do you have **any** sugar?  - **any** means an indefinite quantity
>
> You can choose **any** pizza - **any** means "it doesn't matter which".

Looking at your first example:

> I like dogs. - We are using the plural of dogs to mean "dogs in general"
>
> I like **all** dogs - By adding **all** we really mean "all dogs". It's emphatic.
>
> I don't like dogs - Back to "dogs in general"
>
> I don't like **any** dogs - **any** means "it doesn't matter which"- It's emphatic.

You can emphasise both sentences further by adding "at all", though the second sentence, with double emphasis, is uncommon.

> I don't like dogs **at all**
>
> I don't like **any** dogs **at all**

With the second example, children, we are talking about an indefinite quantity. This meaning does not give any emphasis, so there is no difference between these two sentences:

> Do they have children?
>
> Do they have any children?

The reply could be one of the following: again, "any" does not have an emphatic effect, so there is no difference between the two negatives.

> Yes, I have children
>
> Yes, I have x children
>
> No, I don't have children
>
> No, I don't have any children

You can make the negative sentences emphatic by adding "at all" as we did with the  previous example:

> No, I don't have any children **at all**.

Answer (score 2):

One use of **any** in a negative statement is to emphasize that there are no exceptions. Whether you say **not any** or you put the **not** before a verb,  [**not** plus **any** is an emphatic no (see the section *Not Any and No*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/any).

Without **any**, the sentence below is a general statement:

> I don't like dogs.

This means I don't like dogs in general -- but there may be one or two dogs that I do like. They would be exceptions to the rule.

With **any**, the sentence is absolute:

> I don't like any dogs.
>   This means that there is not one single dog that I like.

Answer (score 1):

When used before plural count nouns, “any” has the meaning of the indefinite article before singular count nouns.

Answer (score -1):

*any* means an indefinite quantity. *I don't like any dogs* - “any" means "it doesn't matter which dog."

*Do they have children? Do they have any children?* We are talking about an indefinite quantity.